# How to cut part of mp4 video using ffmpeg without losing quality?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-capture

hi all i got an mp4 video using ffmpeg but now i want to cut part of this mp4 . For example i only want first 25 min of the mp4 video from 40 min video. could you guys tell me what command i can use in ffmpeg for windows to achieve this task ?

**ffmpeg 40minvideo.mp4**

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i 40minvideo.mp4 -t 1500 -acodec copy -vcodec copy 25minvideo.mp4
```

`-t 1500` processes the first 1500 seconds (25 min * 60 sec/min)

`-acodec copy` and `-vcodec copy` copy the codec data without transcoding (which would incur quality loss).

Comment: Alternatively, `-t 00:25:00` can be used. If the input contains additional video and audio streams then `-map 0` can be added to also copy these since ffmpeg by default will copy only video stream with the highest resolution and the audio stream with the most channels.

Comment: Use `-c copy` for all streams to be copied except the ones which are specified otherwise e.g. `-c copy -c:v:1 libx264` copies everything except the second video stream which will be x265 encoded. @llogan Thanks for the `-map 0`!

Comment: i was getting a frozen frame at the beginning of the vidoe, so after some googling this is what worked out for me `ffmpeg -i videoplayback.mp4 -ss 2 -to 5 -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy output.mp4`